# Why does My.Application.Info.Version always returns 1.0.0.0 in a web service application, when this isn't the correct version

Tags: .net, web-services

Why does `My.Application.Info.Version` always returns 1.0.0.0 in a web service application, when this isn't the correct version that is set in the assembly info properties screen?

It works on an executable, but not on a web service application.

I can get the correct version if I use: `System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName.Version`

Does any one know why `My.Application.Info.Version` doesn't work correctly on a web service application, yet I am still able to access it? I had originally intended to avoid reflection due to performance constraints. (though I don't know the internal workings of `My.Application.Info.Version`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be [not applicable based on project type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aws5xzd2%28v=vs.90%29.aspx). See the requirements section.

Comment: I saw this, but wasn't sure as it didn't list Web Service Application. I know the my. namespace isn't available in a web service or web site, but it is available in a web application and web service application so thought it could be used.